# How to convert SRT file timestamp into milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, srt

I am parsing an SRT file into an object and the schema is like this:

```
[{
    id: '1',
    startTime: '00:00:11,544',
    endTime: '00:00:12,682',
    text: 'Hello' 
}]
```

So, I will need a handy function to convert the timestamps into milliseconds for cross-referencing with my audio file.

Is this a standard timestamp? Can it be easily converted into a `Date` object?

Comment: They are already timestamps. If you want ECMAScript time values, i.e. millisecond offset from the epoch, then you need an associated date. If you just want milliseconds since midnight, then split the values and multiple the parts by suitable factors and add them together.  E.g. `let ms = '00:00:11,544'.split(/\D/).reduce((acc, v, i) => acc += v*[3.6e6,6e4,1e3,1][i], 0)`

Comment: Ok. So should parse into a Date fine?